# Missing views in container after transition to another route

Tags: ember.js

In the OfferRoute I have a container and a controller's method to add views dinamically to it:

```
    addProduct: function() {
        var container = Ember.View.views['containerView']; 
        var child = container.createChildView(Gmcontrolpanel.InsertProductView);
        container.pushObject(child);
    }
```

Everything works fine but if I go to another page on the application and then I come back to the offer page, the child views in the container are missing;
I can see that the HTML output is the empty container:

```
<div id="containerView" class="ember-view"></div>
```

Does someone know why is this happening?

Comment: possible issue may be cached template is getting presented..and you js code may not be getting executed...I am not sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views redraws when you switch pages. So, you get a new containerView instance with empty children list every time.

I'm not recommending to use Em.View.views object for that task. If you need to store state of data between redrawing, it's more likely controller job, and containerView needs to bind to this controller.product list and display each product.

It's possible that {{#each}} helper or custom CollectionView is what will help you to solve the task more elegant.